# Proof verification for $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B) = \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I propose here my proof for:

$$\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B) = \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$$

$\Longrightarrow$
$$x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \land x \in\mathcal{P}(B)$$
$$x \subseteq A \land x \subseteq B$$
$$x \subseteq A \cap B$$
$$x \in \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$$

$\Longleftarrow$
$$x \in \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$$
$$x \subseteq A \cap B$$
$$x \subseteq A \land x \subseteq B$$
$$x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \land x \in \mathcal{P}(B)$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be correct ? :-) Good job !

Comment: Thanks @Surb :) I am just assuming that my proofs have flaws, so I ask for suggestions.

Comment: Just a suggestion. The $8$ lines in your proof can be reduced to $4$ lines. Start with "the following statements are equivalent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>(Just to add an answer to mark this question as answered.)</sub>

Clearly $\mathcal{P}$ means "power set of".

And you're applying the definition of set equality, that is $A=B\iff\forall x \in A, x \in B \land \forall x \in B, x \in A$.

Yes, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$ is the set of all and only the sets which are at the same time subsets of $A$ and $B$. But by definition these are **exactly** the elements of $\mathcal{P}(A)\cap\mathcal{P}(B)$.